# Collision groups and mask?

Tags: game-engine

I have 2 objects that collide, how do I have one of them not collide with anything and still be dynamic? My two objects are a body and a controller, I want the controller to be dynamic so it can fall, but not interfere with bullets; moreover, I want my character to be static so it can collide with bullets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Collision Groups and Collision Mask:

[image]

*Collision groups* are groups of objects generally of the same denomination. You would group objects together based on what their behaviors are, for example; *Bullets, rockets, laser beams and explosive duckling all cause damage to a player, I will put them in group one, my damage group.*

A group can have any number of objects in it, and any object can be in any amount of groups.

*Collision Mask* is the setting that allows you to choose which groups an object will collide with. *I want a certain character to bypass all objects in group one. This includes bullets, rockets, laser beams and explosive ducks, all of which can ruin the invincibility of my character. I* **Deselect** *group one under Collision mask.*

Objects can participate in collisions under any collision group, you can mask/unmask any/all of the groups under this setting.

Although these setting appear similar to layers, I could not find any difference in performance when layers were changed.

Although I was able to explain what your question asked for, unfortunately I was unable to figure out any way for an static object to be the child of a dynamic object without "Major Freak" aside from enabling *Ghost*.

Comment: Oh well, you really want the tick, you well-earned it. I have an issue where it doesn't work with my situation but works with other objects.

Answer (score 2):

For the controller, check the *Ghost* option under the physics tab. This will cause the object to still fall, but there won't be any collisions. You can also parent the character to the controller without having do a major freak-out.

[image: Ghost option]

Comment: That is a way, but I would like to understand how to use collision groups/masks.

Comment: You sure? this is the most efficient for the computer, easiest, fastest, and less prone to unexpected results.

Comment: Yeah, but I am using this situation as an example. I have other situations where I want it to collide with some objects.

Comment: Alright. See if this setup works. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33487

Comment: Ah. It is a sensor, not dynamic. Swap the physics and then see if it works. *it doesn't*

Comment: Darn. You don't want anyone to see this one either?

Comment: Nah. Sorry about that. It just bothers me. I'm trying to come up with something unique, and I had people that would see it and try to replicate, and show others. *Not this time.*

Comment: KK then. Adding another answer with all my studies.